# Formulating Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'TempC3'

```
Itemset      itemset2
       1            3
       2            3
       2            5
       3            5
```

I want combination of elements in these  columns without repetition. So the output table shall be

```
Itemset    itemset2     Itemset3
  1               3            5
  2               3            5
  1               2            3
```

I designed a query but it wont return the last row of the desired output table -

```
Select distinct a.Itemset, 
    a. Itemset2, 
    c.itemset2 
from TempC3 a 
    Join TempC3 c 
        ON c.Itemset2 > a.Itemset2
```

This query only results this:

```
Itemset       itemset2     Itemset3
      1              3            5
      2              3            5
```

Comment: The table got skewed as I am uploading the question from StackExchange app. Kindly understand

Comment: What is the logic behind the last row you want in the output? There is no records in your input table `TempC3` that relates Itemset 1 and 2, so how would you expect it to suddenly appear in the output?

Comment: @Dan Its the combination of itemsets.. Its not combination of columns.. Like we do while Calculating Apriori Algorithm.

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. I will write up an answer now, give me a few seconds.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the logic used to get from the first table (with 2 columns) to the second table (with 3).  What do you mean by "combination"?  I can't deduce the algorithm just from this input and output without more explanation.  I don't understand how you're calculating any of the output columns.

Comment: @Dan thank you so much and sorry for not being able to explain it better. I hope the examples help

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pmbAustin Sir, it is like i have pairs of two values and I create pairs of three values without repetition. {1,2} {1,3} then the output shall be {1,2,3} . {2,1,3} and {3,1,2} ,{3,2,1} shall be discarded as they are duplicates. I hope i am making sense

Comment: ahhh, so you want all combinations where the values increase

Comment: So... if there were four unique values in the original two column table, your desired table would have four columns then? The fact that you've named the columns the same in both before and after is I think VERY confusing given your desired outcome...

Comment: Yes... Inshort i want combination of unique values in pairs of three @pmbAustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want all combinations of itemsets, you have to concatenate the two columns in your input table into a single column first. You could do this, for example, using a CTE:

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/135fc/1)

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Itemset FROM TempC3
    UNION
    SELECT Itemset2 FROM TempC3
)
SELECT I1.Itemset, I2.Itemset, I3.Itemset FROM CTE AS I1
INNER JOIN CTE AS I2 ON I2.Itemset > I1.Itemset
INNER JOIN CTE AS I3 ON I3.Itemset > I2.Itemset
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't thing you need the `DISTINCT` since you are using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`.

Comment: This only return two columns i require three.. I'll explain my problem again sir. I have (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) so the output should be (1,2,3) (1,2,4) & (2,3,4) .. The combination of 1,2,3 in pairs of three

Comment: @Dan thank you sir i did a mistake while copying the code. Works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: I don't think this would work for the desired outcome if there were four distinct values (or more)...